# Evict Entries that are 24 Hours Old Java Spring Cache

Tags: java, spring, caching

I know that it's possible to schedule cache eviction for all entries in a cache by adding the follow method to a class:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 60 * 1000)
@CacheEvict(value = "MyCache", allEntries = true)
public void clearcache() {}
```

Is there an easy way to create a cache eviction policy that will  delete entries that are only older then a certain threshold, say 24 Hours old from the cache each time a method decorated as cacheable is called? So instead of a cache eviction policy as above that will delete all entries when called, is there a way to add logic in the cache eviction to target entries that are "stale"?

Or would it have to be done in a way where the class of the entries we're caching should hold a `long timestamp` of when they are created and cached, and a custom `clearcache()` method can be called that will check all entries, calculate if they're stale, and manually use `cacheManager.getCache("MyCache").evict(ObjectToEvict);` to remove these "stale" entries from the target cache?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It sounds like you want to configure the underlying cache's expiration policy. For example in Caffeine this would be `expireAfterWrite` whereas on Ehcache it would be `time-to-live`.

Comment: @BenManes I think this is what I was looking for. I was initially looking at the simple default caching that spring provides through "@cacheable" but it looks like Caffeine or Ehcache have solutions implemented already. Thanks!